# How disable color from paste

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-5, tinymce-plugins, tinymce-3

I would like so if it's possible in the **Tinymce editor** to disable the color with the copy past from **Word** for example.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: just the color? or **bold**, *italic* as well?

Comment: juste the color

Answer (score 0):

If you `console.log` value in `onEditorChange` event of editor after pasting the text, you can see `style="color: red;"` is added in the pasted text.

In `onEditorChange` you can use regex to remove `color` property from style, and then set the edited value.

```
onEditorChange={(value) => {value.replace(/color(.*?);/i, "")}}
```

Check [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/tinymce-react-demo-forked-4tcjh5)

***Note:** The code is according to tinymce react component. You may need to change some code if you are not using tinymce for react*

Comment: Ok, thanks i go edit that beacause i'm in a Angular project